# asp.net 3.5 upgrade to 4.0 IIS6 ReturnURL issues

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, web-config, iis-6

I have recently upgraded a project from 3.5 to 4.0 everything went great except the ReturnUrl is not doing what it use to. Structure of the project:

All projects are asp.net 4.0:
1. (root): http://example.com
2. (Project1) http://example.com/Project1
3. (MyProject) http://example.com/MyProject <- Virtual Directory. This project is having issues.

Here is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>        
        ...
    </configSections>
    <!--System.net Mail setup-->
    <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp from="support@localhost">
                <network host="localhost" port="25" defaultCredentials="true"/>
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
    <appSettings>
    ...
    <add key="loginUrl" value="Login.aspx" />
    <add key="defaultUrl" value="Home.aspx" />
 </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings>
        <clear/>
        <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb_test;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
        ...
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                ...
                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/></assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <!--<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="PageNotFound.aspx"/>
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="PageNotFound.aspx"/>
        </customErrors>-->
    <pages enableSessionState="true" validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="true" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
            <controls>
                ...
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <httpHandlers>
        ...
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>           
            <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
            ...
        </httpModules>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="458292"/>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
      <!--<forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Home.aspx" protection="All" timeout="60" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies" enableCrossAppRedirects="false"/>-->
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="60" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="Home.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
    </authentication>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Admin"/>
            <allow roles="Student"/>
            <allow roles="Test"/>
            <deny users="*"/>
      <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
        <machineKey validationKey="..." decryptionKey="..." validation="SHA1"/>
        <membership defaultProvider="MembershipProvider">
            <providers>
                ...
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="RoleManagerSqlProvider">
            <providers>
                ...
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
        <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true"/>
        <sessionState cookieless="AutoDetect"/>
        <trace enabled="false"/>
    </system.web>
  <location path="Home.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Login.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="?"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="Logout.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="?"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="AJAXServices">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="?"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="SignIn.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="?"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="ResetPassword.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="?"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="About.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="?"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="ErrorPage.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="?"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="PageNotFound.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="?"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="Assets">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="?"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            ...
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            ...
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>       
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">          
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>  
  </location>
</configuration>
```

The only temp fix that does help is the Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
       if (Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath == "~/")
                HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("Home.aspx");
}
```

Yet with IE 8/9 if I navigate to http://example.com/MyProject it fails but if I do this:
http://example.com/MyProject/ (added a /) it works.  Isn't the defaultUrl suppose to redirect to the main app?  And why is the returnUrl pointing to 
http://example.com/MyProject/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fMyProject%2f

I have searched google and even this site with countless solutions but none seem to resolve it for me.  Perhaps due to this project being in a sub directory of other projects and having a conflict of web.config.

By the way in the Authentication Methods in IIS Enable anonymous access is checked and nothing else is checked.

I don't know what else there might be that is throwing this off.  I have tried to make Home.aspx the main page or Login.aspx doesn't matter.

Additional info:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cscript IisExt.vbs /ListFile

Status / Extension Path
------------------------
0  C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\httpodbc.dll
1  C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\ssinc.dll
1  C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll
1  C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\lib\wsconfig\jrun_iis6.dll
1  C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\lib\wsconfig\1\jrun_iis6_wildcard.dll
0  *.exe
0  C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\httpext.dll
0  *.dll
1  c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll
1  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
```

Also:

```
C:\WINDOWS\microsoft.net\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -lk
W3SVC/  4.0.30319.0
W3SVC/1971902459/root/  4.0.30319.0
W3SVC/1971902459/root/Project1/   4.0.30319.0
W3SVC/1971902459/root/MyProject/    4.0.30319.0
W3SVC/53091907/root/    4.0.30319.0
```

Comment: Do you use rewrite url in your application?

Comment: no the 
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="60" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="Home.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having this issue now.

Comment: No we moved to mvc and started fresh with the project.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to check that you have .Net 4.0 installed fully. As on IIS6 there can be some strange errors with .Net 4.0.

Even though you have installed it and set it up in IIS as the right app pool, out of the box it still wont work.

Use the following guide to make sure that the .dll for .Net 4.0 is registered, otherwise you will end up with a partial working app.

http://johan.driessen.se/posts/getting-an-asp.net-4-application-to-work-on-iis6

Comment: I don't think this is an issue as you can see above with additional information.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about setting the default URL in the config, never tried that before. We always set it in the IIS properties for the app. Maybe check that?

You can check this by:

Right click the app in IIS manager, click properties, click the "Documents" tab, check the "Enable default content page" checkbox, and make sure the correct page is in the list box.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the extensionless url feature introduced in ASP.NET 4 is causing some issues.
Thomas Marquardt has a blog post on disabling this feature [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/06/18/how-to-disable-the-asp-net-v4-0-extensionless-url-feature-on-iis-6-0.aspx).

Give this a try and hopefully your woes will be gone.

Comment: Sorry I tried this also but no go something else must be doing this.  Again this worked perfectly with 3.5...